# Tricky Java: boolean assignment in if condition

Tags: java, initialization, boolean

I'm trying to get prepared for the OCA Java certification and got stuck in some questions dealing assignment in if conditions. Can anyone explain me the reason of the different behaviours in the code below? By my point of view I'm just putting the same two boolean values in an "inclusive or" condition 6 times...

```
package pck;

 class SuperMain{
    boolean b;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new SuperMain();
    }
    SuperMain(){
        if(_true()|_false())
            System.out.println(b); //1 - prints false
        if(b=true|_false())
            System.out.println(b); //2 - prints true
        if(_true()|(b=false))
            System.out.println(b); //3 - prints false
        if((b=true)|_false())
            System.out.println(b); //4 - prints false
        if(b=true|(b=false))
            System.out.println(b); //5 - prints true
        if((b=true)|(b=false))
            System.out.println(b); //6 - prints false
    }
    boolean _true(){return b=true;}
    boolean _false(){return b=false;}
}
```

Comment: Which one don't you get?

Comment: Is this code that you wrote to test yourself, or does this come from a tutorial somewhere? Not only does it have assignment within conditional, it also uses bitwise OR. I assume the cert exams intentionally throw stuff like this on there, but if I received this code in a review, I'd send it back. We don't do this in the real world (well, some do, but not my team).

Comment: @shoover - For Java booleans, bitwise OR and logical OR are equivalent, save for the fact that the second expression isn't evaluated in some cases for logical OR.  (And precedence ;))

Comment: @HotLicks Yes, but it's ugly and intentionally confusing. More problematic is the assignment within conditional, which any decent IDE/lint/PMD will flag. Not to mention the deceiving `return b=false`.

Comment: @shoover - Yeah, definitely the whole thing is intentionally deceiving (and as such would not be reasonable in a regular CS final, etc).  But this is a Java cert, and one presumes they want you to be familiar with some of the really stupid coding practices that one is apt to run across.  The main downside is that someone might see this in the test and take it for good programming practice.

Comment: This was not exactly the same question as the one on the tests, I was just trying to figure out how things like these work. I know this is an unreasonably complex piece of code, this is not how I code, and I never will! But certifications want you to know this mechanisms pretty well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The difference is in [precedence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html). `|` has higher precedence ("binds tighter") than `=`.

So this:

```
if(b=true|_false())
```

is effectively:

```
if (b = (true | _false()))
    ...
```

Likewise this:

```
if(b=true|(b=false))
```

is effectively:

```
if (b = (true | (b = false))
```

In these cases, the assignment of `false` to `b` occurs *before* the assignment of `true` to `b`... so `b` ends up being `true`. In every other case, the assignments occur in the opposite order.

Comment: Thank you! A lot less triky than i thought, i did not consider the operators precedence issue